# windows 7 task bar color change

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I am trying to change the task bar color of my WIndows 7 to black.. something similar to Vista. Is it possible without installing any 3rd party app? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the desktop > Personalize > Window Color?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is! 
Just right click anywhere on your desktop. Select Personalize. 
A new task pane will appear,

Select Window color and choose the color and intensity that you like!